# The max value in a column with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySql table "MyTable" with the column "order"

```
order
-----
3
4
2
1
```

I want to get the highest number. The sql statement works well inside MySql:

> SELECT MAX(order) FROM MyTable"

But I do not know how to use it with php and echo it? Something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(order) FROM MyTable");
```

Comment: If there is something wrong with my question, please explain it and I will repair-inprove it!

Comment: I think the wrong thing is that it can be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: This is NOT your query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(order) FROM MyTable");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Should be `mysqli_fetch_array`, not `$mysqli_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't provide an alias to a MySQL function it will be shown as you've written it:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['MAX(order)'];
```

What you can do is write something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(order) as 'max' FROM MyTable");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['max'];
```

Which is using an alias.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `ORDER BY DESC` and `Limit` result to `1` this way you can easily get the maximum of an column .

```
$result=$con->query("SELECT order FROM MyTable ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT 1");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['order'];
```

Or using MAX

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(order) FROM MyTable");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: The questions asks about the `Max` function, if you want to propose an alternative with `order by`, tell us why.

Comment: I just wanted to inform op that there is also an alternative way he can get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is directly from [tizag](http://www.tizag.com), using the MySql `Max` function
[MySQL Aggregate Functions - MAX()](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlmax.php)

```
// Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT type, MAX(price) FROM products GROUP BY type"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "The most expensive  ". $row['type']. " is $" .$row['MAX(price)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer:

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "your_username";
    $password = "your_password";
    $db_name = "your_db_name";
    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die ("Error:: [1]");
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die ("Error:: [2]");

    $query = "SELECT `order` FROM `MyTable` order by `order` desc";
    $res = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    print $row[0];
```

With this query , you always have the highest value of the give column.